# I tried to make a Camera Controller using the new Input System but there is a problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I was working on a small game project called AliensDefense, where the goal of the game was to shoot aliens. This is my first beginner game project. I made a basic camera controller for the player. But soon, problems started popping up.

There was an error on line 8 "private Vector2 mousePos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();"

I don't know a lot about the new Input System as a beginner. Please guide and assist me, any help would be appreciated. Here is my MouseLook script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class CameraController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 mousePos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
    float xRotation;

    [Header("Basic Attributes")]
    public Transform playerBody;
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity = 1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = mousePos.x * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = mousePos.y * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseX, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: well even if it compiled, it would only get the mouse input at the exact time of creation , never since.. so what does that tell you? (other than its not letting you which makes sense if you think of what I said)

Answer (score 0):

In general when you get errors it makes a lot sense to include them in your question ;)

The error you get

> UnityException: IOCTL is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'CameraController' on game object 'Example'.
> See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.

is telling you that it is not allowed to access the InputActions value as part of a field initialization (which in genera in c# happens in a `static` context before `this` even exists and for most Unity API is no allowed). It is actually also telling you exactly what to do about it

> call it in Awake or Start instead

```
public class CameraController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 mousePos;
   
    void Start()
    {
       mousePos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();

       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**HOWEVER**, as was already pointed out this still doesn't help you at all. What use is a `mousePos` you stored only **once** at the beginning?

`Vector2` is a **struct** and thereby a **value type** and stored as a **copy** and in no way "connected" to the original one returned by `ReadValue`.

You will rather want to retreive the value repeatedly - and don't even need a class field for it at all:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var mousePos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();

    var mouseX = mousePos.x * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    var mouseY = mousePos.y * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseX, 0f, 0f);
}
```